# Stabilize the vector field of $y' = f (y) - \gamma H^T(HH^T)^{-1}h( y ) $ of ODE $y' = f(y)$

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, stability

This question has been asked here but there is no answer:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585400/stabilize-the-vector-field-of-y-f-y-hthht-1h-y-of-ode-y

> > Consider autonomous ODE $y' = f(y)\quad (1)$ which has an invariant set $M$
> >     defined by the equations
> >     $$h (y) = 0 \qquad (2) $$
> >     i.e., assuming that the initial conditions satisfy $h (y (0)) = 0$, the
> >     solution of the ODE satisties $h ( y ( t )) = 0$ for all later times $t\geq 0$. Defined the Jacobian matrix ($y,h\in \mathbb{R}^n$)
> >     $$H(y)=\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}$$
> >     and assume that it has full row rank for all $t$ (in particular, there are
> >     no more equations in (2) than in (1)).
> >     Next we stabilize the vector field, replacing the autonomous (1) by
> >     $$y' = f (y) - \gamma H^T(HH^T)^{-1}h( y )\quad(3) $$
> >     Show that if there is a constant $\gamma_0$ such that
> >     $$|Hf(y)|_2 \leq \gamma_0 |h(y)|_2$$
> >     for all $y$ in the neighborhood of the invariant set $M$ then $M$
> >     becomes asymptotically stable, i.e. $|h(y(t))|$ decreases in $t$ for
> >     trajectories of (3) starting near $M$ , provided that $\gamma\geq \gamma_0$.

I have no clue to prove the claim. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Perhaps an exercise from "Computer Methods for Ordinary Differential Equations and Differential-Algebraic Equations" by Ascher and Petzold?

Comment: @JohnB do you know the proof?

Comment: Hint: $Hy'=Hf(y)-\gamma h(y)$.

Comment: @JohnB Thank you for your hint. Does $|H(f(y))| \leq \gamma_0 |h(y)|$ implies there exits $\gamma_1$ s.t $H(f(y)) \leq \gamma_ 1 h(y)$? If it's true, from your hint I get $Hy' \leq (\gamma_1-\gamma)h(y) => y(h(t))' \leq (\gamma_1-\gamma)h(y) $. This implies that h(y(t)) decreasing in t for trajectories of (3). Am I right?

Comment: Not really, these may be vectors. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$
\begin{split}\frac12\frac{d}{dt} \|h(y(t))\|^2
&=\frac12\frac{d}{dt}\bigl\langle h(y(t)),h(y(t))\bigr\rangle\\
&=\bigl\langle H(y(t))y'(t),h(y(t))\bigr\rangle\\
&=\bigl\langle H(y(t))f(y(t))−\gamma h(y(t)),h(y(t))\bigr\rangle\\
&=\bigl\langle H(y(t))f(y(t)),h(y(t))\bigr\rangle−\gamma \|h(y(t))\|^2\\
&\le \|H(y(t))f(y(t))\|\cdot\|h(y(t))\|−\gamma \|h(y(t))\|^2\\
&\le \gamma_0 \|h(y(t))\|^2−\gamma \|h(y(t))\|^2.
\end{split}$$
The rest is also standard.